# How do I forward a port for a VNC connection in Termius?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, vnc

I am following this guide to VNC into a Digital Ocean Droplet from Termius: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-debian-10

When I try to call the command:

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -C -N -l username server_ip
```

I get the response:

```
bind [127.0.0.1]:5901: Address already in use
```

The docs say:

> If you are using a graphical SSH client, like PuTTY, use
> your_server_ip as the connection IP, and set localhost:5901 as a new
> forwarded port in the program’s SSH tunnel settings.

In Termius, the port forwarding setting asks me for a port from, a destination, and a port to.

What should I enter into these fields? Is the destination the same IP address as the host? What is the port from?